# Разница между значениями «normal» и «none» свойства content в CSS?

Tags: css

Я изучаю CSS и не понимаю разницы между этими двумя значениями (normal и none) свойства «content». Это одинаковые значения? Если да, то зачем мне оба?

```
.p01::before {
  content: none;
}

.p02::before {
  content: normal;
}
```

Comment: При применении к псевдоэлементам разницы нет. Но, свойство `content` может применяться не только к псевдо элементам.

Comment: спасибо болшое....